# Is there a uniform way to define an upper bound on $|X|$ union of $|X|$-sized sets in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Working in ZF (without choice); Let $A \times B$ denote, as usual, the cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$. Let $|X|$ denote the cardinality of $X$ defined after Scott's. Lets define: $$|X|^2= | X \times X |$$

> Does ZF prove that any set union of $|X|$ many sets each of size $|X|$, is subnumerous to $|X|^2$?

> If that fails then is there a definable function on $X$ such that every union of $|X|$ many |X|-sized sets is subnumerous to? Could that be for example $|\mathcal P(X)|^2$?

Comment: Union of countably many countable sets can fail to be countable, so the answer to the first question is no.

Comment: @Wojowu if you don't have choice can you prove that $\omega^2$ is countable?

Comment: Yes, you can give an explicit bijection. Look up Cantor's pairing function

Comment: Your second question is in some sense trivial: if there always exists any upper bound on the size of a union of $|X|$ many $|X|$-sized sets, then there exists a definable upper bound, namely $|V_\alpha|$ for the least $\alpha$ that works.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I said if that *FAILs*. So the question is not trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not even remotely, not even ever.

$\sf ZF$ does not prove that a countable union of countable sets is countable, so for $X=\omega$ your question is already proved false. Moreover, the results of Morris and many others show that $\sf ZF$ cannot even place a bound on cardinalities of countable unions of countable sets.

In other words, it is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that for every set $X$, there is a set $Y$ which is a countable union of countable sets and $|Y|\nleq|X|$. Specifically, Morris proved that it is consistent:

> For every ordinal $\alpha$, there is a set $A_\alpha$ which is a countable union of countable sets, but $\mathcal P(A_\alpha)$ can be mapped onto $\omega_\alpha$.

Recently, I've extended said result to replace $\omega_\alpha$ by $V_\alpha$.

This style of failure of choice can be extended in many different ways, all of which are very terrible.

Comment: That's very interesting! I was thinking such a result might exist but wouldn't know a reference, so thanks for this answer.

Comment: Morris' result was never properly published, so it remained a bit of a mystery until recently; others, I'm sure, had similar results about as soon as Easton support products came about, but I cannot tell you where and when exactly someone proved something like that. None of the results, however, beat that of Morris (except, of course, my improvement, for obvious reasons).

Comment: very interesting indeed, many thanks for this answer!

Comment: Can one establish a "local" bound? Maybe something like: If $X$ is a countable union of countable sets, then $X\in V_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is below the first ...? (Where of course the value of "the first ..." depends on the model but "..." is "reasonably defined".)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: No, because of Morris. Also because that would provide you with an upper bound in the form of $V_\alpha$.

Comment: Oh, I was reading the quantifiers wrong ("for every $\alpha$ there is a model ..." instead of "there is a single model in which for each $\alpha$ etc.").

Comment: @AsafKaragila is this result of Moris (and your strengthening of it) is due to that union being not well orderable? I mean I was under the impression that we can have some bounds if we restrict ourselfs to well orderable sets, I mean if I have a countable union of countable sets, that is well orderable, then my guess is that $\omega_2$ would be a strict upper bound on its size? like for example when having a countable union of countable sets of ordinals, this would be well ordered, and it cannot exceed $\omega_2$ right? (due to Jech's result?)

Comment: @Zuhair: If the union if well-orderable it can be countable or size $\aleph_1$. So you could only reach an ordinal which is the surjective image of $\mathcal P(\omega_1)$ or $\Bbb R$.